# Render partial from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm still relatively new to Rails so please bear with me. How can I refresh the partial and stay at the page instead of rendering only the partial?

In `_interaction.html.haml`:

```
%div.vote_up.pull-left
  = link_to('', vote_up_deal_path(deal), :method => :post, 
    :class => 'icon-thumbs-up interaction_button', :id => "vote_up_#{deal.id}")
```

In 'votes.js':

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/deals/' + id + '/vote_up',
  success: function() {
    //do stuff
  }
});
```

In my `deals_controller.rb`:

```
def vote_up
  if user_signed_in?
    current_user.vote_exclusively_for(@deal = Deal.find(params[:id]))
    render :partial => 'deals/partials/interaction', :locals => {:deal => @deal}
  end
end
```

This will redirect me to the page and render the partial instead of refreshing it like an AJAX request should.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
= link_to('', vote_up_deal_path(deal), :method => :post, :remote=>true, 
    :class => 'icon-thumbs-up interaction_button', :id => "vote_up_#{deal.id}")
```

because :remote says that it is ajax request